# Count Unique Cells Matching Results in Set

Tags: microsoft-excel

I've got a single column of coded data in Excel like this:

```
a
b
ab
bc
ad
b
ac
```

I know I can find the instances of all cells containing "a" with `=COUNTIF(A1:A7,"*a*")`. That would give me 4. I can also count "b" `=COUNTIF(A1:A7,"*b*")` which results in 4.

However, what I need is to count cells that contain "a" OR "b" but **doesn't double-count** cells containing both. `=COUNTIF(A1:A7,"*a*")+COUNTIF(A1:A7,"*b*")` = 8, but I want an OR condition that would count 7 by not double-counting "ab".

If this were regex, I could do something like `=COUNTIF(A1:A7,"[ab]")` but I can't...

---

UPDATE: As noted in [a comment](https://superuser.com/questions/786103/count-unique-cells-matching-results-in-set/786104#comment1023456_786104), this is a simplified example. I have A-M in the dataset and may need to count combinations of two, three, or even seven different values, so I need a solution that can scale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution should work as a scalable implementation that can be easily expanded for other strings.

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(FIND("a",A1:A7))+ISNUMBER(FIND("b",A1:A7))>0))
```

Example of adding another string:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(FIND("a",A1:A7))+ISNUMBER(FIND("b",A1:A7))+ISNUMBER(FIND("c",A1:A7))>0))
```

This works by running the `FIND` function on each cell in the range, and using `ISNUMBER` to determine if a match was found. The results are added up for each cell, and then the `>0` at the end specifies that any cell that matched at least one of the `FIND`s should be counted. The `SUMPRODUCT` adds it all up to produce a final answer.

For a case-insensitive match, you can replace the `FIND` function with `SEARCH`.

Comment: Thanks. That would solve the issue though it wouldn't appear to scale well. Counting three values would require subtracting all the various combinations. I'm looking for something that can handle that more cleanly. Sorry for not making that clearer. I've updated the OP.

Comment: @mrwweb Good point. I updated my answer, let me know what you think of this solution.

Comment: Awesome! Worked great. There was one misplaced parenthesis at the end. This is what I needed to get it working: `=SUMPRODUCT(--(ISNUMBER(FIND("a",A1:A7))+ISNUMBER(FIND("b",A1:A7))**)**>0)`